# How to make nohup not create any output files and so not eat all space?

Tags: debian, nohup

So I start some server with `nohup ./myServer &`, I actually have loging mon my server so I do not need any help from nohup with it, but any way I get `66GB` `nohup.out` file in fiew days and that is a problem. I want just to start an app, leve it working on its own. So how to make nohup not  create any output files and so not eat any space?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Redirect the output to `/dev/null`:

```
nohup ./myServer >& /dev/null &
```

Alternatively, if you want to discard the standard output but keep the standard error, you could use this:

```
nohup ./myServer > /dev/null &
```

You can find more details here if you need more control over the redirections (using bash):

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html
- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 0):

I just learned of the `setsid` utility today; I don't know why it took me so long. You can run your process like this using the setsid utility:

```
setsid ./myServer
```

> setsid runs a program in a new session. The command calls fork(2) if already a process group leader.
> Otherwise, it executes a program in the current process. This default behavior is possible to override by the
> --fork option

`/usr/bin/setsid` is installed with the util-linux package on Ubuntu with a minimal install.